# invalidargumentexception credentials.json" does not exist

Tags: php, google-api, craftcms

I am trying to use Google APIs with craft cms. To pull data from my calendar from Google. I modify the quickstsrt.php that Google had on Github. That works but when I went to add the code to my Craft plugin it's not able to find the JSON file anymore

I have the same code working outside of craft. I have gone through the google results and was not able to find any solution that would work. it may be the why I authorized my google account but like I said the PHP works outside of craft

```
public function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig(credentials.json);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

// Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
$tokenPath = 'token.json';
if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
}

// If there is no previous token or it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        // Check to see if there was an error.
        if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
            throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
        }
    }
    // Save the token to a file.
    if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
        mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
return $client;

InvalidArgumentException: file "/home/mesicdev/www/craft/plugins/credentials.json" does not exist in /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/plugins/calendarpuller/src/services/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:870
```

Stack trace:

## 0 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/plugins/calendarpuller/src/services/CalendarService.php(87): Google_Client->setAuthConfig('/home/mesicdev/...')

## 1 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/plugins/calendarpuller/src/services/CalendarService.php(60): campnonet\calendarpuller\services\CalendarService->getClient()

## 2 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/plugins/calendarpuller/src/controllers/CalendarController.php(63): campnonet\calendarpuller\services\CalendarService->getCalendarInfo()

## 3 [internal function]: campnonet\calendarpuller\controllers\CalendarController->actionDefault(true)

## 4 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)

## 5 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)

## 6 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(109): yii\base\Controller->runAction('default', Array)

## 7 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('default', Array)

## 8 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(297): yii\base\Module->runAction('calendar-puller...', Array)

## 9 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction('calendar-puller...', Array)

## 10 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(286): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))

## 11 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))

## 12 /home/mesicdev/public_html/craft/web/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()

## 13 {main}

Answer (score 1):

you have an error in this line

`$client->setAuthConfig(credentials.json);`

This should be a path to a real file.

use this instead:

`$client->setAuthConfig("/path/to/credentials.json");`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did add my path which is /home/mesicdev/www/craft/plugin/credentials.json is on the code on the server the same error happens. i tired to set the path as a variable. like this $credentialsfile = 'paht/to/json'

Comment: stack trace added

Comment: i have also noticed that my postcode as a typo in it. I have fixed the typo that wasn't causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I am wrong for whatever reason I forgot to add the /src folder when typing my path to json Thaks for your help